# Where are the contents of the `history` command stored in Linux and Why does SIGKILL to the terminal doesn't prevent it from storing the commands?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Let me tell the things which i have tested . 
The `history` command shows the last 2000 or so commands entered by the user in the terminal .

I found that the contents of history are stored in the `bash_history` in the user's home directory .

But the weird thing which I can't quite get my head around is that :

- When I print the contents of bash_history while working in a terminal , it doesn't show me the commands that I entered in the present terminal session. The commands in the present session would only be saved in the bash_history file once I close the terminal .
- But when we execute the history command, it prints the contents of the bash_history and also the commands of my present terminal session . Where is this temporary file ?
- I concluded that , the commands of current sesesion only gets appended to the bash_history file , once the user closes the terminal.

  ---

#### The confusion starts  here : -

- When I kill the current terminal process with `kill -9 $PPID` command  , it should not have been able to save these commands of current session to the bash_history file since `SIGKILL` can't be handled .
- But when I reopen the terminal , and execute the `history` comamnd , it still shows all the commands which I had entered in the terminal session before I killed it brutally. How is this possible ? Does'nt kill signal 9 mean , there is no furthur instruction execution from the process ? How is it still storing even after killing it   ?
- THE WEIRD THING :-  When I am in a terminal session with some commands entered before and if I type `sh` and press enter. I would be in the normal shell with the `$` prompt  . From here if I give the `kill -9 $PPID` command , the current terminal process gets killed . However now , the commands entered in the session before going to the `sh` shell WON'T be saved to the `bash_history` file . Why doens't this occur when I kill the process from the default bash shell of the terminal and why do the commands don't get saved when I kill the terminal process from the `sh` shell in the same terminal.
- One more thing , what is the file called `bash_history-03092.tmp` doing in my home folder ? I found that this file is always empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man bash`, the `$PPID` variable stores

> The process ID of the shell's parent.  This variable is readonly.

When you open a terminal in a graphical session, you have a process of a terminal emulator that presents a window for you and a `bash` (or other shell) running in it.
So when you execute the `kill -KILL $PPID` command you kill a process immediately, but **not the `bash` itself** but a GUI showing you a terminal. Then your `bash` process is somehow informed that its parent process dies (or maybe it looks for pseudo terminal close and not a parent process termination -- I don't know exactly) and exits cleanly.

But when you execute `kill -KILL $PPID` from `sh` launched from your `bash`, it is your `bash` that is "parent process" and that is killed immediately without the possibility to flush its history to file.